# Stored Procedure returning more than 1 result set

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, return, multiple-resultsets

I have read that a stored proc can return more than 1 result set.

Lie it can be defined as below.

```sql
CREATE PROC Sales.ListSampleResultsSets
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP (1) productid, productname, supplierid,
categoryid, unitprice, discontinued
FROM Production.Products;
SELECT TOP (1) orderid, productid, unitprice, qty, discount
FROM Sales.OrderDetails;
END
GO
```

If this is the case how does the caller access each individual result set.

Thanks

Comment: You would have to tell us at least what the database system is that you're using, and where you're calling this stored procedure from (what language / programming system). There's no universal answer to this - depends on your language and database system

Comment: Thanks, its just SQL Server 2008